# req.file and req.body not working while using multer 2.0

Tags: javascript, multer, cloudinary

### multer.js

I am using multer@2.0.0-rc.1, according to their documentation the code is as follows

```
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer().single("avatar");

module.exports = { upload };
```

### Userroute.js

```
 const { upload } = require("../middleware/multer");
 router.route("/register").post(upload, registerUser);
```

### Controller for User Registration

I am not able to access the `req` object. The error is shown after code

```
const catchAsyncError = require("../../middleware/catchAsyncError");
const ErrorHandler = require("../../utils/errorhandler");
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
```

```
 exports.registerUser = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => 
 {
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.file);
 });
```

## **Console**

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
null
```

Answer (score -2):

Try modifying the module. Exports to `module.exports` and also

```
const upload = multer().single("avatar");
```

can be changed to

```
const upload = multer.single("avatar");
```

Hope this works.

Comment: multer.single("avatar") is not working